# Is it possible to switch off the strictness analyzer on GHC?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

It shows `ghci` is lazy all round below,

```
ghci > let x = trace "1" 1 in x + x

1
1
2
```

Running the code below after compilation shows default `ghc` is enhanced by [strictness analyzer](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fstrictness).

```
main = do print $ let x = trace "1" 1 in x + x

1
2
```

But why does the result remain same even if the options `-O0 -fno-strictness` are passed to `ghc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with strictness. The behaviour of GHCi is actually just silly if you think about it: it “computes” `x` twice. Lazy or not, a constant shouldn't need to be calculated twice!

What's going on: `x` has a generic number type `Num a => a`. That means, its implementation is not really just a constant, but a function with a “type”- (actually, a *dictionary*-)argument. Functions are generally not feasible to memoise, so such a polymorphic value *is* recomputed whenever you need its value. That's annoying, hence standard Haskell avoids this by a somewhat controversial measure, the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction). It basically eliminates polymorphism if it can thereby turn values into [constant applicative forms](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constant_applicative_form). So `x` is inferred with the simpler type `Integer`, which *is* then a constant which only triggers `trace` the one time it's computed whereas the second evaluation just re-uses the already known value. (Which is the “proper lazy” behaviour!)

The reason you don't see this in GHCi is that since version 7.8, it has the monomorphism restriction turned off by default! You can turn it on to see what this does:

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Debug.Trace
Prelude Debug.Trace> let x = trace "1" 1 in x + x
1
1
2
Prelude Debug.Trace> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction 
Prelude Debug.Trace> let x = trace "1" 1 in x + x
1
2
```

Fortunately, in an actual program the double evaluation will not happen even with the monomorphism restriction turned *off*, because when `x` is defined in a function body the compiler can see that *within the scope of the function*, it is not polymorphic. Hence your second code should never trace `1` twice. (Though always keep in mind, `trace` is just a crude debugging tool that really works against the language's grain – generally don't expect any reproducible behaviour from it.)

Comment: You don't even need to enable the monomorphism restriction to demonstrate the difference, you can simply give ghci an explicit type instead of letting it infer a polymorphic type: `let x = trace "1" 1 :: Int in x + x`

Comment: This isn't the monomorphism restriction being off. It's `let` generalization being on. GHC must be using the fact that `x` is used twice at the same type, I guess, while GHCi uses the most general type. Or something. This all seems a bit weird.

Comment: @dfeuer, GHC doesn't use the most general type because it would violate the monomorphism restriction. And the last paragraph of the answer is not really right, in a compiled program (without optimizations) you will see the same results as in ghci if you use `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}`.

Comment: @ReidBarton, well, I guess it's a sort of combination effect. Consider `let x :: a; x = trace "1" 1 in x+x :: forall a . Num a => a`.

Comment: @ReidBarton: sure? Even with `ghc -O0 -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` I don't get a duplicate trace.

Comment: My guess would be that it's because in ghci the result is bound to the implicit `it` variable. With no monomorphism restriction that stays polymorphic, so `x` has to be polymorphic. The **use** of that during printing gets defaulted, but the binding is polymorphic so the think isn't overwritten. But in the full program compiled with ghc, the result of `x + x` never goes anywhere polymorphic so the original binding of `x` gets defaulted, and is monomorphic.